# Show convexity and find the extreme points of this set

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Given the following set
$$
D = \{ (x_1, x_2) \in \mathbb R^2: x1 \geq \frac{x_2}{2} + 6, x_2 \leq 3, x_1 < - (x_2-2)^2 +10\}
$$

I want to show that is is convex and find its extreme points.

To show convexity I'm stuck at showing that the set given by $x_1 < - (x_2-2)^2 +10$ is convex. I know that after that I can use the fact the the intersection of convex sets is convex.

For the extreme values I think that the only extreme value should be the intersection of the two line $x_2 = 3$ and $x_1 = \frac{x_2}{2} + 6$, but I don't know how to justify it.

Comment: Remember, a set given by $c(\mathbf{x}) < 0$ where $c$ is a convex function is a convex set. You can use this fact to help show that the set given by $x_1< -(x_2-2)^2+10$ is convex.

Comment: I strongly suggest you graph the three inequalities forming $D$. Also, what do you mean by "extreme points"? Every point on the boundary of $D$ is extreme in some sense. That is what the boundary is.

Comment: @PaulSinclair: I'm using this definition of extreme point https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_point

Comment: And did you pay any attention to that example they gave, where those three circular arcs are all extreme points? Have you noticed that your set also has a curved side?